# How practical is fracture mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics

I have been reading [fracture mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_mechanics) recently and have encountered many beautifully elegant theories.  However, one thing keeps bothering me: How practical is fracture mechanics in the real world?

I want to ask this question for several reasons:

1. Many formulations (e.g. stress intensity factor) is only applicable for very simple geometry.  Most problem in reality involves 3D non-planar geometry, which analytical expression might not be available, and it is not clear how to approximate them numerically.
2. In my impression (which could be wrong) fracture mechanics theories are dealing with one crack at a time.  However, in practice, each sample could contain millions of cracks.  Treating them one by one is not tractable.
3. Knowledge of crack geometry (at least crack length) is necessary in most of the theories in fracture mechanics.  However, for brittle material, the crack is often too tiny to be noticeable before failure, making it not practical to model crack geometry in simulations.

These reasons are based on my limited knowledge.  I don't mean to offend any researchers in the fracture mechanics field.  I am just confused about how to put the theory into practice and hope it is not just a game of mathematics.

Comment: I don't know enough for a full answer, but 1. you can simulate the appropriate equations numerically, so not having an analytical expression is fine 2. cracks are often far enough apart (in early stages anyway) that they don't interact, so you can just handle them separately 3. In some cases microscopic techniques are used to detect cracks. The theory may also be used the other way around (i.e. don't need to know the crack dimensions, just the energy where it goes critical so that we know our limits)

Comment: Thanks Robert for your answer.  However, my doubt persists.  Without knowing the the geometry, location and quantity of cracks in a sample that is not a plane or a rectangular bar (which is often the case in reality), it just seems hard to apply the theories from fracture mechanics.

Comment: You assume that we want to start from full knowledge of the cracks. What we'd rather do is use a good model of the fracture structure to predict how more easily measurable quantities relate to each other and to the internal structure. So I don't start out with "I have cracks shaped like this here, here and here", I start with "I measured these parameters, which *imply* the cracks inside are somewhat like this, so this part needs to be replaced". The theory is also useful in [forensic engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_engineering), for different reasons.

Answer (score 3):

At minimum--understanding the complex case is going to be impossible until you understand the simple case.  People working on fracture mechanics are definitely doing experiments to validate what they see, and they are definitely explaining some subset of the problem.  In fact, what is awesome about this field is that it's one of the few remaining areas where one person can do an experiment, and then go and do theory for that experiment.

For instance--almost no motion in the atmosphere is truly parabolic.  Often it deviates wildly from parabolic motion.  But it would be foolish to say that it's useless to study basic kinematics--any understanding of what is going on will depend critically on understanding kinematic motion, even if you have a knuckeballing baseball or whatever.

Comment: Thanks Jerry!  Understanding the theory for simple setup is definitely important for understanding more complex cases.  From a practical engineer's perspective, I guess my question is with our current knowledge, is it possible to bridge the gap between theory and reality in fracture mechanics?  If so, how it is done?